Is there any way to specify an "optional" MSBuild global using directive (<Using />) in C#?
I have the following <Using /> property for my projects:
<ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="Maybe.NonexistenceNamespace" />
    <!-- More -->
</ItemGroup>

Now that namespace may or may not exist in a project. However, if it does not exist, I receive this compile error (which is understandable)

CS0400    The type or namespace name 'Maybe' could not be found in the global namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Is it possible to tell C# compiler to ignore such directive if that namespace does not exist?
Context: I have many directives like that in a separate Import.targets file that is reused by many (hundreds of) projects. They are imported into the final production project using <Import />. It's rare that a few namespaces are missing but there are some. Unfortunately the missing namespaces are not unique (this project may miss these namespaces, other project may miss a few others)
Right now the workaround I am using is to add <Using Remove="..."/> to those projects but it's quite hard to manage:
<Using Remove="Maybe.NonexistenceNamespace"/>


If an assembly that provides the namespace is not referenced then the using statement will cause the CS0400 error. You could disable the CS0400 error but that would be counter-productive. You want to know when the reference is missing.
It seems the issue is that you are applying all possible using statements but not every project uses every assembly.
A given assembly can have multiple namespaces and there may be no relation between the namespace names and the name of the assembly.
The referenced assemblies are generally added via a ProjectReference or PackageReference. Less commonly there may be a direct Reference.
The reference and the using(s) should probably be set together, e.g.:
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(UseMaybeNonexistenceNamespace)' != ''">
    <PackageReference Include="Maybe.NonexistenceNamespace" />
    <Using Include="Maybe.NonexistenceNamespace" />
  </ItemGroup>

If code like the above is in your Import.targets file, a project could set the $(UseMaybeNonexistenceNamespace) property before the Import of Import.targets to add both the PackageReference and the global Using.
This still doesn't quite eliminate the management issue but I would suggest that "the management issue" is intrinsic to having a global file for global usings. For a given project the references are generally not changing frequently. If each project manages its own references and usings and there is no global file, then the coordination issues of a global file won't exist.

Hmm interesting approach, you are right I didn't think about the "other way around". Yes I probably should break up the big Import.targets file into multiple smaller files (and still have a big one for projects that use it often).

Btw just curious, you said "You could disable the CS0400". Is this actually possible? I thought about this before as I don't think this is bad (is it?). Assume I want to do that, how do I do it? I don't think we can ignore compiler error like warnings

You are right. The CS0400 is an error, not a warning; and errors can't be disabled like warnings.
